# How to put parameters as kwargs in Postman

Tags: django, api, rest, postman, keyword-argument

I will use kwargs in django in python but I do not how to put parameters as kwargs?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the tab 'Params' you can set GET parameters, is that what you're looking for?
[image]

**Update**:

if you have a url like this defined : `path('some/path/<int:mynumber>', ...)/`

Then to send that in Postman you simple do: `http://localhost:8000/some/path/23/`.

Comment: Hi thanks four your reply. But when attaching parameters under param, API reads parameters under *args. I want to transmit parameters under **kwargs. Here is the difference.

Comment: Can you attach a sample of your code of your view in Django and I think i can help you. I've updated my answer to what I believe you mean.